# How to response Well formatted errors as JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Hi I'm new in C# currently I'm building my first web API. The requirement is to display any error that happen as a response in JSON format

**This is my ResponseData Class**

```
public class ResponseData 
{
    public List<AccountDTO> AccountList { set; get; }
    public string ReturnMessage { set; get; }
    public string error { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string innererror { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string stacktrace { get; set; }

}
```

**This is my Controller**

As an example, If my code execute the `catch` block, I'll will gather all the information of the exception and return this in a formatted `JSON`.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ResponseData getAllAccounts(string BRN, string CompanyName)
    {

        ResponseData response = new ResponseData();
        List<AccountDTO> accountlist = null;
        IAccountInterface usecase = new AccountDAO();
        try
        {
            if (BRN != null && CompanyName != null)
            {
                accountlist = usecase.getAccountbyBRNCompanyName().Where(p => p.BRN.ToLower().Equals(BRN.ToLower()) && p.CompanyName.ToLower().Contains(CompanyName.ToLower())).ToList();
                response.ReturnMessage = "Data filter by BRN and CompanyName.";
            }

            else
            {
                response.ReturnMessage = "Data filter cannot be null.";
            }
            response.AccountList = accountlist;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message + ", Stack: " + e.StackTrace);
            response.code = "sample code";
            response.message = e.Message;
            response.innererror = "{";
            response.message = e.Message;
            response.type = "ExceptionType + ...";
            response.stacktrace = e.StackTrace;



            //response.ReturnMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorFormat);


        }

        return response;
    }
```

After run this web APi the response is as per picture below if catch block is executed. 
[image]
So far, It's almost similar to what I want. However regardless errors or not, my WEB API response will be in this format. I know this is because I return a `response object` so all my object properties will be displayed.

This is a sample response that I want to achieve. Details about errors are included as JSON in the response. Errors will be in this format. Any help and guide greatly appreciate.

```
{  
 "error":{  
  "code": "<This code is not related to..>",  
  "message": "<A message describing the error..>",  
  "innererror": {  
   "message": "<A message describing the error..>",  
   "type": "Microsoft.Crm.CrmHttpException",  
   "stacktrace": "<Details from the server about where the 
                  error occurred>"  
    }  
   }  
}
```

Comment: the desired JSON error response model does not match the class used.

Comment: @Nkosi kindly elaborate more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired JSON error response model does not match the class used.

The current object model is serving multiple responsibilities.

Consider refactoring the class models to serve a single responsibility

```
public class ResponseData {
    public List<AccountDTO> AccountList { set; get; }
    public string ReturnMessage { set; get; }
}
```

The API action can also be refactored to return the appropriate response based on the flow of the action.

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult getAllAccounts(string BRN, string CompanyName) {
    try {
        ResponseData response = new ResponseData();
        List<AccountDTO> accountlist = null;
        IAccountInterface usecase = new AccountDAO();
        if (BRN != null && CompanyName != null) {
            accountlist = usecase.getAccountbyBRNCompanyName().Where(p => p.BRN.ToLower().Equals(BRN.ToLower()) && p.CompanyName.ToLower().Contains(CompanyName.ToLower())).ToList();
            response.ReturnMessage = "Data filter by BRN and CompanyName.";
        } else {
            response.ReturnMessage = "Data filter cannot be null.";
        }
        response.AccountList = accountlist;
        return Ok(response);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message + ", Stack: " + e.StackTrace);
        var response = new {
            error = new {
                code = "sample code",
                message = e.Message,
                innererror = new {
                    message = e.Message,
                    type = e.GetType().Name,
                    stacktrace = e.StackTrace
                }
            }
        }
        var responseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, response);
        return ResponseMessage(responseMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tqsm @NKosi, help to achieve what I want. I'll accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message + ", Stack: " + e.StackTrace);
        response.error.code = "sample code";
        response.error.message = e.Message;
        response.error.innererror = "{";
        response.error.message = e.Message;
        response.error.type = "ExceptionType + ...";
        response.error.stacktrace = e.StackTrace;
```

This should get you your desired result.  response object would also have to be refactored.

Comment: Thanks @NewfrontSolutions, but response.error doesn't have such property. How can I refactor this object ?